# Switch between two pages in Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I want to create an application like reddit. I have read the Oracle documentation and I didn't find how to switch between pages.

How to switch between two pages in Swing application?

Comment: *"How to switch between two pages in Swing application?"* Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Tabbed Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), it is the best for storing pages.

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");

JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1,
                  "Does nothing");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", icon, panel2,
                  "Does twice as much nothing");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

JComponent panel3 = makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", icon, panel3,
                  "Still does nothing");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3);

JComponent panel4 = makeTextPanel(
        "Panel #4 (has a preferred size of 410 x 50).");
panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 50));
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 4", icon, panel4,
                      "Does nothing at all");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_4);
```

Comment: I would like to have separate pages and somehow navigate between them. Tabs don't seem what I am looking for, is there any better solution?